# PL/SQL function with date parameter returns wrong output

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, sql-function

In order to make my main code more readable, I have wrapped an operation to convert a date to epoch format in a function. However, the function returns an incorrect value. What am I doing wrong?

**What I get**
*Function*

```
create or replace function date_to_epoch(
        date_in in date)
        return number
        is
            epoch_out number;
            begin
            epoch_out := round((to_date(date_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))*24*60*60);
            return epoch_out;
            end;
```

I call the function with:

```
declare
    date_out number;
begin
select date_to_epoch(to_date('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) into date_out from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Output:' || date_out);
end;
```

returns: -62134128000

**What I expect**
I get the expected output when I run the same operation in a simple SQL statement:

```
select round((to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date('1970-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))*24*60*60) from dual;
```

returns: 1577836800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

The [`TO_DATE` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) has the signature:

```sql
TO_DATE( date_string, format_model, nls_param )
```

Where all the arguments are expected to have a string data-type.

You are not passing a string as the first argument; you are passing a `DATE` data type. Oracle will try to be helpful and convert the `DATE` you are passing to a string by implicitly calling `TO_CHAR` using the current session's NLS date format session parameter.

So, your function is effectively:

```sql
create or replace function date_to_epoch(
  date_in in date
) return number
is
  epoch_out number;
begin
  epoch_out := round(
                 ( to_date(
                     TO_CHAR(
                       date_in,
                       ( SELECT value
                         FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                         WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
                     ),
                     'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
                   )
                   -
                   to_date(
                     '1970-01-01',
                     'yyyy-mm-dd'
                   )
                 )*24*60*60
               );
  return epoch_out;
end;
```

To fix it, you need to just use the date input as a date rather than trying to convert something that is already a date to a date:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION date_to_epoch(
  date_in IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ROUND( ( date_in - DATE '1970-01-01' )*24*60*60 );
END date_to_epoch;
```

However, you also need to make sure that your dates are in the UTC time zone and if they aren't convert them to UTC before calculating the epoch:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION date_to_epoch(
  date_in  IN DATE,
  timezone IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'UTC'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ROUND(
    ( CAST(
        FROM_TZ( date_in, timezone ) -- Convert to a timestamp in the correct TZ
        AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'           -- Change to the UTC TZ
        AS DATE                      -- Cast back to a date
      )
      - DATE '1970-01-01'
    )*24*60*60
  );
END date_to_epoch;
/
```

So:

```sql
SELECT date_to_epoch( DATE '1970-01-01' )        AS utc_epoch,
       date_to_epoch( DATE '1970-01-01', 'PST' ) AS pst_epoch
FROM   DUAL;
```

outputs:

> ```
> UTC_EPOCH | PST_EPOCH
> --------: | --------:
>         0 |     28800
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a50436d70e1448f2cbebcf07da978f6)*

Comment: It works, thank you. The suggestion to make sure the input dates are in UTC is a good one as well. In my case I have to assume that the input date is in UTC as I my data source does not contain timezone information. But based on your suggestion, I will make the main code  a bit smarter, so it can recognize differences due to timezone and DST.

Comment: @honeybees - if you live, for example, in Tokyo, and all your business is there, an equally likely assumption (if not more so) is that all dates are in Tokyo time zone. This is not something **you** should make assumptions about; rather, ask your business users. (Or ask those who set up the data model - they may know what time zone was assumed.)

Answer (score 2):

Your input parameter is a date already, so you should not use `to_date()` on it. Bad things happen when you do that.

I would write your code as:

```
create or replace function date_to_epoch(date_in in date)
return number
is
    epoch_out number;
begin
    epoch_out := round((date_in - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60);
    return epoch_out;
end;
```

Note that you don't actually need an intermediate variable to store the return value of the function. You can directly do:

```
create or replace function date_to_epoch(date_in in date)
return number
is
begin
   return round((date_in - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60);
end;
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b8a0962e418fa08193fbcf78197223bb)**, the code yields:

```
Output:1577836800
```

Comment: As the function is, in fact, deterministic, I would add that to the function declaration. It may help in various ways.

Comment: @mathguy Could you you give a small example of a situation where it would help?

Comment: @honeybees - if you need to use the function in a function-based index, or in a constraint, the function **must** be deterministic.